# Почему "пищаль"?

Tags: этимология

Всегда было очень интересно, почему на Руси старинные ружья называли "пищали"? На писк их звук никак не похож, а других аналогий в голову не приходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пищаль.** Ближайшая этимология: ж. "дудка", "вид огнестрельного оружия", пищаль.
От *пищать*, праслав. *piskělь,* piščalь; ср. *свирель*. (по Фасмеру).
Думаю, дело здесь не в звуках, издаваемых пищалью, а в форме: пищаль похода на дудку.